# "pause" being ignored

Tags: unit-testing, batch-file, automated-tests, phpunit

I read that I must be able to run all unit tests in my site with a single command, so I created a bat file to do it.

Even with pause before the end, after the phpunit command, the result of the unit tests flashes in the screen.

```
@echo off
cd c:\
cd xampp
cd htdocs
cd light
cd myworks
echo on
set /p site=The site:
set /p version=The version:
set /p location=The location:
phpunit "%site% v%version%/%location%"
pause
```

My other batch file with java %folder%/%file% runs the java software, then pauses.

```
@echo off
cd c:\
cd Codes
cd 1st general - Head First Java
echo on
set /p folder=Type a folder:
set /p file=Type a file without extension:
java %folder%/%file%
pause
```

UPDATE: it's much easier to run the unit tests with SimpleTest than with phpUnit.

Comment: What happens if you open cmd and run you batch file from within?

Comment: It asks for the site, then the version, then shows the result, but the word pause doesn't appear

Comment: apropos, `cd c:\ ` will only chage CWD on C:, but your "current" drive could remain something else. so, instead `c:` and then `cd "/xampp/htdocs/light/myworks"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `call phpunit ...`

Comment: The difference here is that java is probably an `exe` and phpunit a `bat`. The bat will switch execution and never return without the `call`.

Comment: Very nice, would've never found this out myself.